BH350 Strain gauge Arudino naon
I have changed the strain gauge of BH350 modules with another strain gauge of equal 350 ohm strain gauge, but after the change, the readings are only 1 or 2. It's like there is no strain gauge connected to the module. Even when I tried to increase the current by nob of the module, no reading was there. Any Solution? Please help.
Or if there is any other solution like can i connect 2 wire strain gauge to HX711 module?

where did you get the picture?  ... it says that you are not allowed to copy it

Come on, it is just a picture. Give me an answer if you have one. It not an area69 project

you cannot post copyrighted material here

The HX711 is optimized for 4-wire or 3-wire configurations, and directly connecting a 2-wire strain gauge to the HX711 may not yield the expected results. Moreover, the HX711 module requires a complete Wheatstone bridge configuration to operate, and if your strain gauge is not configured within the bridge, you may not get any meaningful readings.
Connecting a 2-wire strain gauge directly to the HX711 module could further complicate the situation, and it is not recommended.
You can refer to pages 5 and 6 of this HX711 pdf document:
https://www.jakelectronics.com/pdf/datasheets/8465c9553d41406e1902912c0f8c8929?product=aviasemiconductor-hx711-68717131
